# How to set image brightness to back it's original brightness?

Tags: jquery, image, brightness, pixastic

I am using [Pixastic](http://pixastic.com/) for performins image operations. Currently I am using it's Brightness/Contrast Code.

Here is the HTML Code

```
<input type="range" id="brightness_range"  min="-150" max="150" value="0" />
```

and this is jQuery code of Pixastic

```
jQuery('#brightness_range').change(function(){
        var img = document.getElementById ('image');
        var brightness_val = parseInt(jQuery('#brightness_range').val());
        Pixastic.process(img, "brightness", {brightness:brightness_val});
    });
```

I am able to set it's brightness but I am not able to take it to back.

Let me explain... For example I changed Slider value to 25 then brightness set to 25 but if I drag my slider value to 0 again from 25 then it's not setting the original brightness of Image... :(

I think it is adding value every time first 25 then plus 25 (50) .

Please guys help me I asked similar questions yesturday but not getting any response from stackoverflow .

And I think  there is no other option to change brightness of image using slider or if Please tell me.

**Thanks!!!**

Comment: Use debugging in firefox or chrome to check the value of 'brightness_val' after it has been assigned. If it is what you expect then the problem is in the behaviour/your usage of pixastic.
Edit:
Sorry, accidently sent when I was still writing :P

Comment: @Flipbed value of what ? Image is converting into Canvas when We use Pixastic.process

Comment: @Flipbed I can check the value of brightness_val by alerting it but as I told image is converted into canvas I am not able to see what is the brightness of image when it was loaded and after changing it to back it is adding in changed not decreasing.

Comment: Yes but if you use debugging in firefox or chrome you can freeze the javascript at a certain point to view the value of 'brightness_val' and check that it in fact does have a lower value when you expect it to. Check this video on how to do debugging in chrome: http://youtu.be/htZAU7FM7GI?t=3m9s

Answer (score 0):

Every pixastic action is performed -on top of- the canvas. So actually you are first doing a brightness of 25, and then a brightness of 0 (which is doing nothing).

To make this work as you expect, change your code to the following:

```
jQuery('#brightness_range').change(function(){
    var img = document.getElementById ('image');
    var brightness_val = parseInt(jQuery('#brightness_range').val());
    Pixastic.revert(img); // Note that this is an undocumented feature, but it exists.
    Pixastic.process(img, "brightness", {brightness:brightness_val});
});
```